# C# read and write a file with a given buffer length and cut overflow

Tags: c#, filestream

i want read a file in 1MB chunks with a FileStream and write it back with another FileStream.

The problem i have, is that the file with ~2.9MB get up to ~3.9MB because the last buffer is to big for the data (so it gets filled with \0 i think).

Is there a way to cut the overflow of the last buffer?

```
public static void ReadAndWriteFileStreamTest() {
        string outputFile = "output.dat";
        string inputFile = "input.dat";
        using (FileStream fsOut = File.OpenWrite(outputFile))
        {
            using (FileStream fsIn = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
            {
                //read in ~1 MB chunks
                int bufferLen = 1000000;
                byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferLen];
                long bytesRead;
                do
                {
                    bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, bufferLen);
                    fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                } while (bytesRead != 0);
            }
        }
    }
```

Any help would be great! :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**PROBLEM:**

```
fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
```

writes all bytes from the buffer, while you read only `bytesRead` amount.

**SOLUTION:**

You should use `bytesRead` as third parameter of [FileStream.Write](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) - `count` - amount of actually read bytes to avoid writing of bytes that aren't actually read.

```
do
{
     bytesRead = fsIn.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
     fsOut.Write(buffer, 0, bytesRead );
} while (bytesRead != 0);
```

Comment: Well, now i think it was a stupid question. :) Can accept the Question in 6 minutes ....